# How to fit an uniform distribution to a histogram?

Tags: matlab, histogram, uniform-distribution

I have a set of data that is generated from an **uniform** distribution. Now I want to fit the corresponding histogram to an uniform distribution, such that there is a 'ㄇ' shape of line plotted on that histogram. I tried to fit it by using the MATLAB built-in function `histfit`, but there is no such an option of uniform distribution for [histfit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/histfit.html). How can I do it?

```
data = unifrnd(-100,100,1000,1);

%% MATLAB built-in function: 'histfit'
figure(1);
hh = histfit(data); % No options for 'histfit' to fit data to an uniform distribution

%% Manually fitting a histogram to an uniform distribution
figure(2);
numBars = length(hh(1).XData);
histogram(data, numBars);
% TODO: How to do next to plot a line that fits the data to an uniform distribution?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a uniform distribution is just 1/(b-a) for a region [a, b), you can define a function that calculates this

```
x = -200:200;
y = unifdist(x, -100, 100);

figure;
plot(x, y)

function ret = unifdist(x, a, b)
  ret = ones(length(x), 1)/(b-a);
  ret(x < a | x >= b) = 0;
end
```

There's probably a much simpler and faster way to do this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

`min(data)` and `max(data)` give an estimate of the two parameters of the uniform distribution, assuming `data` is uniformly distributed.

Note that this is a biased estimator, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60497/unbiased-estimator-for-a-uniform-variable-support) for a correction to remove the bias (one of the answers considers the case where the lower bound is not 0). [Link thanks to @flawr.]

Comment: It is maybe worth noting that `a = min(data), b=max(data);` correspond to the [Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @CrisLuengo's answer, you could use the [Method of Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) to estimate the parameters `a,b` of the uniform distribution `U[a,b]`. Following equations are sufficient to solve for the parameters. The MoM just tells us to equate the (sample-) mean and variance to the distribution mean and variance:

```
mean(samples) = (a+b)/2,    variance(samples) = (b-a)^2/12
```

This results in `a, b = mean(samples) +- sqrt(3 * variance(samples))`. In MATLAB you can compute this as follows:

```
m = mean(data);
v = var(data);
a = m - sqrt(3*v);
b = m + sqrt(3*v);
```

To plot this you can just define vector

```
x = linspace(-lower_limit, upper_limit, number_of_points);
y = (a < x) .* (x < b) ./ (b - a);
plot(x, y, '-r');
```